# Is there any conditions i can include in Find() in win32com library

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Python library : win32com
Task : find and locate a cell address in excel spreadsheet where the value(string) is 'Offset'.

Problem: i have another cell named 'Byte Offset' in M6
The 'Offset' is in R6.

If i use Find('Offset') it gives me the 'Byte Offset's location.
$M$6

I tried
Startswith
Endswith
FindNext
xlWhole from VBA

Above is not available in win32com library.

Even in the excel application if i use Find and search for Offset, it first locates the Byte Offset, after clicking FindNext Offset is located,

I will need a loop for find out in usedrange until i can find value == 'Offset'.

Help me resolve this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using Pandas or another library to interact with the xlsx file rather using Excel directly?

Comment: You can achieve this using win32com. Perhaps show us what you have tried that is not working? Pretty much everything in the Excel object model is available with win32com.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MartinEvans, i cannot continue with pandas, they want me to continue in win32com itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DS_London, 
i used the common way
Cell=workbook.Sheets(sheetname).UsedRange.find(value)


now i have solved this problem using
for i in workbook.Sheets(sheetname).UsedRange:
      if i.value == "Offset":
      print("Cell address:", i.Address)